# Есть определенные произвольные числа. Нужна функция, которая будет выводить которая будет приводить число к аналогичному числу с другим промежутком

Tags: javascript

К примеру, есть числа от 0 до 25 и нужна функция, которая будет выводить эти числа к аналогичным числам с 15 до 35. (0)=> 15, (20) => 29, (25) => 35

Comment: Стоп, чего? А по подробнее можно?

Comment: вы имеете в виду масштабирование значений одной шкалы (от 0 до 25) к значениям другой шкалы со значениями от 15 до 35? или что вы подразумеваете?

Comment: Ищите линейную интерполяцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Линейная интерполяция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F): если даны два отрезка можно построить линейную функцию, которая отображает первый отрезок (`(x0, x1)`) на второй (`(y0, y1)`). Функция имеет вид

> ```
> y = ax + b, где
> a = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
> b = y0 - x0 * a
> ```

Подстановкой проверяется что `x0` отображается в `y0`, а `x1` в `y1`.

```
const make_linear_interpolator = (x0, x1, y0, y1) => {
    const a = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);
    const b = y0 - x0 * a;
    return x => a * x + b;
};

const li = make_linear_interpolator(0, 25, 15, 35);

for (const x of [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]) {
    console.log(x, li(x));
}
```

> ```
> $ node linear_interpolation.js
> 0 15
> 5 19
> 10 23
> 15 27
> 20 31
> 25 35
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Элементарнейшая арифметика. От 0 до 25 - 100%, абсолютная длина - 25, сдвиг - 0. От 15 до 35 тоже 100%, абсолютная длина - 20, сдвиг - 15.

20 -> 80% от 25 (длина первого интервала). Соответственно берем 80% от 20 (длина второго интервала), получается 16. Плюс сдвиг 15, итого 31. А не 29 как у вас.

Вывести формулу и перевести все это в код на любом языке можете самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

**как и писали выше функция следующая, сначала мы определяем абсолютное соотношение в процентах, а далее умножаем на него и прибавляем сдвигаемое значение**

```js
function numberConversion(num) {
  let convert = num * 0.8 + 15;
  return convert.toFixed(1);
}
console.log(numberConversion(25));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]